# How can I fill empty space with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am using XSLT to transform an xml to a slash delimited text file.  In part of my xml I need to create the following:

```
HEADING
/1    /2                   /3       /4     /5 /6        /7
/data /data                /data    /dat   / 1/data     /data
```

Where there is a heading and the numbers are column titles with rows of data underneath.  The spacing between each column must be the same but the data can have a length less than the needed space between the columns.  I'm using this to get the value:

```
<xsl:value-of select="package_identification"/>
```

What can I do to pad any leftover space with blank spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two ways that I can think of.

**XML Input**

```
<test>
    <row>
        <entry>data</entry>
        <entry>dataaaa</entry>
        <entry>data</entry>     
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry>datadata</entry>
        <entry>datad</entry>
        <entry>da</entry>       
    </row>
</test>
```

**First XSLT 2.0**

This uses literal spaces to represent the column width. It also uses `substring()` to strip off what it doesn't need...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="colwidths" as="element()">
        <colwidths>
            <col val="                 "/>                 
            <col val="         "/>
            <col val="                       "/>                         
        </colwidths>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <xsl:variable name="currPos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',.,substring($colwidths/col[$currPos]/@val,string-length(.)))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Second XSLT 2.0**

This is similar, but uses digits to represent the column width and uses `xsl:for-each` to output the spaces needed...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="colwidths" as="element()">
        <colwidths>
            <col val="17"/>                 
            <col val="9"/>
            <col val="23"/>                         
        </colwidths>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <xsl:variable name="currPos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',.)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="0 to xs:integer($colwidths/col[$currPos]/@val - string-length(.))">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both of these produce the following output:

```
/data              /dataaaa   /data                    
/datadata          /datad     /da
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use EXSLT, use the str:padding function: http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/padding/index.html

Assuming you wanted a column to be 10 characters wide, working off your line of XSLT:

```
<xsl:value-of select="package_identification"/>
<xsl:value-of select="str:padding(10 - string-length(package_identification))"/>
```

Make sure to declare xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings", preferably on the xsl:stylesheet element.

If you can't use EXSLT, then define a recursive padding template:

```
<xsl:template name="padding">
  <xsl:param name="length"/>
  <xsl:param name="string" select="' '"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
  <xsl:if test="$length > 1">
    <xsl:call-template name="padding">
      <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length - 1"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$string"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Then use it like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="package_identification"/>
<xsl:call-template name="padding">
  <xsl:with-param name="length" select="10 - string-length(package_identification)"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```